# Yii2 Caching Active Record

Tags: php, yii2

I need help with caching Active Record data in Yii2.

In documentation has example:

```
$result = Customer::getDb()->cache(function ($db) {
    return Customer::find()->where(['id' => 1])->one();
});
```

I understand that it need to implement the method in model class such a:

```
public static function getByPk($pk)
{
    $result = self::getDb()->cache(function ($db) use ($pk) {
        return self::find()->where(['id' => $pk])->one();
    });

    return $result;
}
```

If this query result was already cached in `$result` will set value from cache, otherwise will execute query, correctly?

Also I have question about dependency, what dependency I can use for invalidation this cache value?

Answer (score 0):

As an opinion! You know it depends on data that you add to cache storage. If it's some static data such as status, position etc. you can set the second param `duration`. You can read about at official [doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#query-caching-usages).
If you make a few same queries on the page you can set 1 or 2 seconds and it helps you a little.